# Функция WriteFile из WINAPI

Tags: c++, windows

Уточню на всякий случай, что речь идет о [функции](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
Заметил, что она пропускает символ перехода на другую строчку: `"\n"`. Как для этой функции сделать переход строки?

**UPDATE:**

Пример кода:

```
int main()
{    
    string PathEXE = "C:\\Projects\\tests\\Release\\";
    auto file = CreateFileA((PathEXE+"logtest.txt").c_str(), GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("ERROR %x \n", GetLastError());
        std::cout << "\nRELOAD NEEDED. LOG ERROR";//messagebox
    }
    DWORD size = 0;
    std::string text = "\n1";
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        WriteFile(file, text.c_str(), (text).size(), &size, NULL);
        size += (text).size();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE2:** Когда писал вопрос, открывал файл обычным блокнотом(Windows 7). Сейчас открыл Notepad++ и там есть переходы на другую строчку Оо. как так?

Comment: Что-то я не вижу в документации на `WriteFile` информации о том, что какие-то символы пропускаются. Имеет смысл предположить, что баг в вашем коде. Покажите, как именно вы пишете, и как проверяете результат. (Обязательная ссылка: [mcve].)

Comment: Она не может ничего пропускать, т. к. работает с байтами, а не с текстом.

Comment: @VladD пример добавлен

Comment: Проблема не в WinAPI, а в софте которым вы смотрите получающийся файл. Инфа 146%.

Comment: для переходов в виндосовском блокноте нужно писать `\r\n`, Notepad++ понимает обе записи и windows и *nix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема вот в чём.

Когда вы пишете строки в файл через стандартные потоковые функции (и файл открыт как текстовый, а не как бинарный), происходит перекодировка на лету из сишных концов строк (`\n`) в системно-зависимые (на Windows `\r\n`). И в файл попадают концы строк вида `\r\n` (можно проверить любым hex-редактором).

Когда вы пишете через `WriteFile`, он ничего не знает о строках, и пишет в файл как есть. То есть в файл попадают концы строк вида `\n`. (Можно снова-таки проверить любым hex-редактором.)

Как правильно подсказывает @Grundy в комментарии, блокнот воспринимает лишь концы строк вида `\r\n`. С другой стороны, в стандарте Unix концы строк имеют вид `\n`, и ваш файл по существу непреднамеренно оказывается в этом формате. Поскольку другие редакторы понимают этот формат, они интерпретируют ваш файл как текст Unix, и показывают его так, как вы хотели.

---

Решение — либо добавьте `\r` перед `\n` в ваши строки, либо пишите через стандартные строковые функции языка.